# OAuth2.0 Provider in Google Appengine. Without google account - Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to implement a OAuth2.0 provider. I know Appengnine provides a library for that but looks like the users will be required to have a Google account. 
Has anyone found a way around this?
Basically I want to have my own user authentication system and allow them to grant access to other apps(clients/consumers)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, not sure if its the best way..I used the OauthLib for python and built it..
I also blogged a rough outline on how I did it. If interested here it is.
http://shakirthowseen.blogspot.com/2014/10/implement-oauth-2-provider-in-google.html